# Are many sites closed during New Years Day in Milan?

Tags: italy, milan

Are many sites, businesses, and transportation services closed during New Years Day in Milan?

Comment: as an aside, your question got flagged as low quality, because of its length.  It always helps to add detail, indicate exactly which sites you were hoping to see, or what specifically you're interested in, next time.

Comment: @MarkMayo Yeah, sorry about that. I didn't have specific places in mind. I sort of wanted to just wander around; hence the vague quesiton. But your answer below addresses exactly what I had been looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New Years day is a [public holiday there](http://www.milano24ore.net/shopping/opening_hours.php).  So yes, many places will be closed.

Indeed, many shops stay closed until the 6th, with winter sales starting again on the 7th of January.

This is reflected in a post on [tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g187849-i143-k313583-Milan_at_new_year-Milan_Lombardy.html):

> Restaraunt wise we were amazed at how many closed over New Year. I
>   expected some would be closed on the 1st but some were closed from the
>   31st till the 6th! We did struggle to find a place to eat a couple of
>   times and ended up having to go to one of the numerous self service
>   restaurants which are fine but not exactly what we were looking for on
>   holiday.

and this recommendation on the same page:

> I live in Milan and I personally do not reccomend to spend the new
>   year in the city.
>
> Basically there is nothing to do.
>
> Milan people usually go out of the city for new year's eve: to ski, on
>   the lake, in the coutryside, to visit other cities. The situation is
>   different in the other Italian cities, like Rome or Florence.
>
> Of course many restaurant and clubs are closed, maybe is the worste
>   day to see Milan.

So long story short (unless you have specific sites in mind, in which case I'd check their individual websites), in general a lot of stuff is closed during this holiday period.